# Facial Recognition Fail Events

Tags: android, face-recognition, facial-identification

Is it possible to capture fail events from facial recognition software like Face Unlock? (Android)

I'd like to program a method that's triggered when it doesn't recognize the user. My concern is if there's a simple way to piggy back off of the pre-installed software, then it would not only be less code, but also less wasteful of resources; otherwise, it would be redundant to build a separate application to mount the method. Unfortunately, there's not a ton of documentation on these pre-installed smart unlock applications.